# Huge request SQLAlchemy multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, sqlalchemy, raspberry-pi3

I have a huge request on database running on a Pi but it's taking too long and only one CPU core. 
So my question is how can i split my request in multiple request and combine the result after all ?

I'm currently using SQLAlchemy and SQLite :

```
session = sessionmaker(engine)()
session.query(Object).filter(one).filter(two).group_by(func).all()
```

It's take 30s to get the result with 100% usage of 1 core, i hope i can cut in half the time with 4 core. Am I too optimistic ?

EDIT :
Use PostgresSQL is pertiant or not ? If i want a hight level of multithreading ?

Comment: Recent versions of SQLite have multithread support for certain operations. But grouping is not one of them, and it would be hard to do manually. Are there obvious partitions in your data?

Comment: Yes date is the index and i group by date

Comment: I was thinking to split the request in 4 request and merge the result but i don't know how to do that in a beautiful way

Comment: If you were to switch to Postgres, this would be many times faster with no code changes.